# Creating exception in Java

Tags: java

I am taking a `String` from the user as input which is then turned into an `int`. I want that this value to be from `1` to `4` and if this is greater than 4 a message should be output. Can someone help me to display this message if this number is greater than 4? This is my current code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String nr;//marrim nje string dhe
        nr=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Jepni nr e lojtareve");// krijojme nje input Dialog qe shfaqet ne ekran  ne menyre qe te na lejoje te fusim nje string si input(nr i lojtareve)
        //marrim string pasi input Dialog merr vetem stringa si input dhe e konvertojme me vone ne int
        int n=Integer.parseInt(nr);//e konvertojme ne int stringen qe morem pasi na duhet vlera e saj 
        String[] emrat=new String[n];// vektori qe ruan ne te aq emra jojtaresh sa vlera int  einputit qe dhame
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            emrat[i]=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Jepni emrin");//Shfaqet aq here sa kemi dhene nr e lojtareve nje tjeter input Dialog per te vendosur emrat e lojtareve
        }
        Background  d = new Background(emrat) ; 
     }
}
```

Comment: You could at least take the time to format your code properly if you want us to volunteer our time to help you

Comment: @NeilBartlett a poorly named variable

Comment: Sorry for the comments

Comment: If you lookup Integer . parseInt in the JavaDocs you will see `public static int parseInt(String s) throws NumberFormatException` -- this should be a huge hint.  If you are not familiar with JavaDocs you should be...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an `if` statement to check whether the gotten integer is

- lower than one
- higher than four

If these conditions apply, the number is invalid and you can exit your `main()` method using a `return;`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String nr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Jepni nr e lojtareve");
        int n = Integer.parseInt(nr);
        if (n < 1 || n > 4)
        {
            System.err.println("...");
            return;
        }
        String[] emrat = new String[n];
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            emrat[i]=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Jepni emrin");
        }
        Background d = new Background(emrat);
    }
}
```

Also, I highly advise against cluttering your code with apparently meaningless comments. It will not help with the readability of it, but make it more cluttered and harder to read.